# Adding Simple Calculations to SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add a few columns that will calculate columns from a query. I tried adding it towards the end of the query but it errors out at the "AS" when I am naming the column. This query works without the calculation step, so it may be because the calculation should be done elsewhere?

Thank you all in advance for any help!

```
     SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT   
         col_1,
         col_2,
         col_3,
         col_x
    CASE
         WHEN col_1 = '' THEN col_x     
           ELSE col_2 
    END AS FINISHEDCASE, 
    col_1, 
    col_2, 
    col_3,
    col_x, 
    (calc_1*(1-(calc_2/100)) AS calc_column 
         [**Desire to
         add several columns that reference selected columns, ie,col_1, 
         col_2, etc. onto the
         end of the query**]
    
    FROM TABLE_NAME 
      LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME_2 
    ON col_a = col_b
          )as subquery

WHERE Fieldname NOT IN ('D')
```

The expected result of the query should look as follows

col_1, col_2, col_3, col_x, calc_column

Running the query right now gives an error message at the 'AS' clause.

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to ask here; sample data and expected results and your *actual* attempt (the above has several syntax errors) will help us help you.

Comment: Ok I have added an edit. I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: That SQL still has multiple syntax errors, and you didn't provide any sample data or expected results.

Comment: There are so many errors here. Why are you using a subquery here at all? And why does your subquery return the same columns multiple times? Unless you can provide table definitions, sample data and desired output nobody can help you with this.

Comment: Perhaps get rid of the outer part of the query filtering on FieldName to start.  If it is required, then it needs to be selected in the subquery.  Also, uses aliases on the 2 tables.  If col1 exists in both tables, you need to use the alias to get the value from the correct table.  Use something like select cal1 as [Table1_col1] to know what column is what if col1 is returned form both tables.  Use an alias on every column so reader don't have to guess or look at the table definitions.  Otherwise, you should be able to add more calculated columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot of guess work what you really intend to do but as I understood it, you like to calculate two calculated values (`calc_1` and `calc_2`) and then use them as an intermediate result to further calculate a column (`calc_column`). That could be done like this:

```
WITH Calculated AS (SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, col_x, (col_1 + col_2) AS calc_1, (col_3 * col_4) AS calc_2 FROM TABLE_NAME)
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, col_x, (calc_1*(1-(calc_2/100))) AS calc_column FROM Calculated
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use CROSS APPLY with VALUES.  Each calculation can then be returned:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (formula1, formula2)) AS c(calc_1, calc_2)
 WHERE ...
```

You can then use the calculations anywhere else in the query as needed.  You can even stack CROSS APPLY to calculate variables that can then be used in following CROSS APPLY statements.  For example:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (col1 + col2, col3 + col4)) AS v(a, b)
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (v.a * v.b)) AS e(c)
```